# Emacs mode function parameter type inconsistensy

Tags: emacs

I have noticed that Emacs `*-mode` functions sometimes take `t|nil` as an argument, sometime it must be `-1|1`. I think in the first case it is fine provide `-1|1` instead of `t|nil`, but in the second case it lead to a unexpected behavior providing `t|nil` instead of `-1|1`, correct me if I am wrong.

```
(blink-cursor-mode -1) ; Must be -1, nil not going to work
```

I personally like more `t|nil` because it feels more explicit, rather than numbers.

Why it is like this? Is there any convention? What would be a consistent way to enable/disable, would `-1|1` work everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a `t|nil` convention, please report mode commands that expect that as bugs.

Fore reference see [major mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html) and [minor mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minor-Mode-Conventions.html) conventions.